# C++ Passing struct function as parameter for a function in an inherited struct

Tags: c++, struct, parameter-passing

I have two structs, struct B inherits from struct A. I want to pass a function as a parameter from struct B to struct A for struct A to use.

This is an example of what I want to achieve and the issue I'm running into, the full code would be TL;DR.

```
struct A
{
    int32 mynum;

    void Tick(float delta, bool doThis, void (funcparam)(float, bool, int32))
    {
        funcparam(delta, doThis, mynum);
    }
};
```

---

```
struct B : public A
{
    void RunThis(float deltaTime, bool doIt, int32 which)
    {
        // do something when called by Struct A
    };

    void DoSomething()
    {
        Tick(0.1f, true, &B::RunThis);
    };
};
```

The issue is with this line: `Tick(0.1f, true, &B::RunThis);` from the function `void DoSomething()` unless I've done it wrong from the beginning, but I imagine I am passing it wrong since it's still within the header of the struct that I'm currently defining?

Error (I have modified the error to fit my example, I don't think I messed up..):

`error C2664: 'void A::Tick(float,bool,void (__cdecl *)(float,bool))': cannot convert argument 3 from 'void (__cdecl B::* )(float,bool)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(float,bool)'`

Omitting the `B::` from `&B::RunThis` of course doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Look into `std::function()`, your function pointer `void (funcparam)(float, bool, int32)` isn't able to take member function pointers.

Comment: ``void (funcparam)(float, bool, int32)`` is not what you want. First, the signature of a (non-member) function pointer is ``void (* funcparam) (float, bool, int32)`` (you missed the *). Second, you  could make Tick() a function of the base class, which then calls a virtual function, which yo override in the derived class. This is still a better approach compared to using ``std:function``, as long as you have a 1:1 relationship of "derived class" : "function you want to be executed."

Comment: @BitTickler - that was a MUCH better solution for my purpose, thank you! As for the answer to the specific question, I'll still wait for it to be posted up so that people who google similar issues have an accurate answer

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - That seems right, if you can post up an answer with a short example I'll tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option: Use a virtual function instead.

Works best if you have 1 and only 1 function per derived class anyway.

```
struct A {
    virtual void RunThis(float deltaTime, bool doIt, int32 which) = 0;
    void Tick(float delta, bool doThis )
    {
        //...
        RunThis(delta, doThis, which);
        // ...
    }
    virtual ~A() // virtual destructor...
    {}
};

struct B : public A
{
    virtual void RunThis(float deltaTime, bool doIt, int32 which )
    {
    }
    void DoSomething(/*...*/) 
    {
        // ...
        Tick(/*...*/);
    }

};
```

Second option: std::function + lambda or member function in struct B

```
#include <functional>
struct A 
{
     void Tick(float delta, bool doit, std::function<void(float,bool,int32)> action )
     {
     }
};

struct B : public struct A
{
    void DoSomething( /*...*/ )
    {
         // you can use a lambda, if convenient...
         Tick(/*...*/,
             [this](float delta, bool doit, int32_t which) -> void {
                // ...
             });
   }

   // or you can also use a pointer to member:
   void RunThis(/*...*/) { /* ... */ }
   void DoSomething(/*...*/)
   {
        std::function<void(float,bool,int32)> f = std::bind( &B::RunThis, this, _1,_2,_3);
        Tick(/*...*/, f);
   }
 };
```

Comment: Or a lambda and a method instead of `std::bind` with `[this](float delta, bool doit, int32_t which){ return this->RunThis(delta, doit, which); }`

Comment: @6502 Yes, the only thing not working would be to try and pass the lambda to A::tick() without a std::function, as then, the type would be unknown...which I still don't consider a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately C++ function pointers do not have context... in other words a pointer to function accepting an integer

```
void (*f)(int x)
```

is not allowed to have any data "bound" to the pointer and can only access parameters and global variables.
A work-around implemented for some compilers are ["trampoline" libraries](http://linux.die.net/man/3/trampoline) that allow binding custom data to function pointers, but they all rely on dynamic code creation at runtime, something not possible within the boundaries of standard C++.

The solution in standard C++ is to use

```
std::function<void(int)>
```

instead of

```
void (*)(int)
```

An `std::function` object can keep data associated with the function and allows the creation of closures. It is also backward compatible with function pointers (i.e. a function pointer can be implicitly converted to an `std::function` object).

Using that your code can become for example

```
struct A {
    int32 mynum;
    void Tick(float delta, bool doThis,
              std::function<void(float, bool, int32)> funcparam) {
       funcparam(delta, doThis, mynum);
    }
};

struct B : public A {
    void RunThis(float deltaTime, bool doIt, int32 which) {
        // do something when called by Struct A
    };
    void DoSomething() {
        Tick(0.1f, true, [this](float dt, bool di, int32 w) {
            this->RunThis(dt, di, w);
        });
    }
};
```

where a lambda has been used to call the method.

A portable workaround if you cannot change the code accepting a function pointer is to have a preallocated set of function pointers for a given signature... for example

```
void *closure_data[10];
void (*closure_code[10])(void *, int);

void closure0(int x){ closure_code[0](closure_data[0], x); }
void closure1(int x){ closure_code[1](closure_data[1], x); }
void closure2(int x){ closure_code[2](closure_data[2], x); }
...
void closure9(int x){ closure_code[9](closure_data[9], x); }

void (*closures[10])(int) = {closure0,
                             closure1,
                             ...
                             closure9};
```

and then you need to "allocate" a closure `i`, putting your context data in the corresponding `closure_data[i]`, the code in `closure_code[i]` and pass as function pointer `closures[i]`.

Normally decent C++03 code or C code accepting function pointers for callbacks always provide a context parameter... i.e. the interface has the form

```
void Tick(void *context,
          void (*callback)(float, bool, int32, void *))
```

and will call the callback also passing the opaque `void *context` specified by the caller that provided the function pointer.

Comment: There /is/ pointer to member ( ``void( Foo::* funcptr)()``) in C++. But to make this work in this case, struct A would have to know about struct B, which obviously is undesirable.

Comment: @BitTickler: A pointer to member in C++ doesn't carry any context and requires an object to be applied on. If an API call accepts a function pointer unfortunately you cannot pass a pointer to member... they are different abstractions (the exception are of course `static` member functions... those are indeed just regular functions with a funky name).